# Show different data in view

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a view t1 that looks at Table t1, and i would like for that view to show the same data as in t1 except one column, example:

TABLE T1

### Id           Name          Salary

```
1002         Alden          4000
2343         Lawson         4500
2004         Barbra         4800
```

VIEW T1

### Id            Name        Salary

```
1002         ANON           4000
2343         ANON           4500
2004         ANON           4800
```

Do i need to use a function in the select statement, because if i create view as update statement it changes also the content in the original table. I dont know is it possible to write a `select Name as "ANON"` but that changes all data in the column to that input and not just the name of the column or something in that line. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.T1
AS

SELECT ID,
       'ANON' AS Name,
       Salary
FROM dbo.T1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i knew it has to be simple, and ofc i forgot the basics, was coding the hole day and my function is at the lowest possible lvl. When i get the 15 reps i will come back and upvote you. Cheers